# Optimize binary classification model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, ai

I've created binary classification model from scratch, just to understand intuition behind that.

However when I compare my implementation to model from tensorflow/pytorch with the same parameters and configuration I noticed that my model achieved similar results in about **3 000 epochs** but tensorflow/pytorch model achieved that in **300 epochs**.

I also noticed that my model calculates very small gradient when tensorflow/pytorch calculates a much higher gradient in every epoch

- Is there any way to optimize calculating gradient in `backward` function to make model learning faster?
- Is there any other such field that could be optimized/simplified and how could it be implemented

Below is my `backward` function responsible for calculating gradient:

```py
def backward(
              y: np.ndarray,
              y_pred: np.ndarray,
              layers: List[ Dict[ str, np.ndarray ] ]
            ) -> None:

    loss: np.ndarray = binary_cross_entropy_loss_prime(y, y_pred)

    for layer in reversed(layers):
        dZ: np.ndarray = layer['prime'](layer['z']) * loss
        layer['db'] = (dZ * np.ones_like(layer['b'])).sum(axis = 0, keepdims=True) / loss.shape[0]
        dU: np.ndarray = dZ * np.ones_like(layer['u'])
        layer['dw'] = np.dot(layer['x'].T, dU) / loss.shape[0]
        loss = np.dot(dU, layer['w'].T)
```

and also full code with data types to easier understanding:

````py
"""# Dataset and libraries"""

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from typing import List, Dict

from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
x, y = make_moons(n_samples = 1000, noise = 0.2, random_state = 100)

# expand y second dim
# before expand_dims -> y.shape = (1000, )
# after expand_dims -> y.shape = (1000, 1)
y = np.expand_dims(y, 1)

# final shapes: X -> (1000, 2), Y -> (1000, 1)

"""# Activations functions"""

def sigma(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigma_prime(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
  e = np.exp(x)
  return e / (e + 1) ** 2

def relu(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
  return np.maximum(0, x)

def relu_prime(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
  return np.where(x <= 0, 0, 1)

"""# Dense layers"""

dense_layers = [
      { 'w': np.random.rand(2, 8) * 0.1, 'b': np.random.rand(1, 8) * 0.1, 'activ': relu, 'prime': relu_prime },
      { 'w': np.random.rand(8, 8) * 0.1, 'b': np.random.rand(1, 8) * 0.1, 'activ': relu, 'prime': relu_prime },
      { 'w': np.random.rand(8, 1) * 0.1, 'b': np.random.rand(1, 1) * 0.1, 'activ': sigma, 'prime': sigma_prime }
]

"""# Losses and metrics """

def binary_cross_entropy_loss(y_true: np.ndarray, y_pred: np.ndarray) -> float:
  number_of_rows = y_true.shape[0] # 1000 rows
  number_of_cols = y_true.shape[1] # 1 cols
  return np.sum(-(y_true * np.log(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * np.log(1 - y_pred))) / number_of_rows * number_of_cols

def binary_cross_entropy_loss_prime(y_true: np.ndarray, y_pred: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
  return (1 - y_true) / (1 - y_pred) - y_true / y_pred

def accuracy(y_true: np.ndarray, y_pred: np.ndarray, threshhold: float = 0.5) -> float:
  return (np.where(y_pred <= threshhold, 0, 1) == y_true).mean()

"""# Forward propagation"""

def forward(x: np.ndarray, layers: List[ Dict[ str, np.ndarray ] ]) -> np.ndarray:
  for layer in layers:
    layer['x'] = x
    layer['u'] = np.dot(x, layer['w'])
    layer['z'] = layer['u'] + layer['b']
    layer['a'] = layer['activ'](layer['z'])
    x = layer['a']
  return x

"""# Backward propagation"""

def backward(y: np.ndarray, y_pred: np.ndarray, layers: List[ Dict[ str, np.ndarray ] ]) -> None:
    loss: np.ndarray = binary_cross_entropy_loss_prime(y, y_pred)

    for layer in reversed(layers):
        dZ: np.ndarray = layer['prime'](layer['z']) * loss
        layer['db'] = (dZ * np.ones_like(layer['b'])).sum(axis = 0, keepdims=True) / loss.shape[0]
        dU: np.ndarray = dZ * np.ones_like(layer['u'])
        layer['dw'] = np.dot(layer['x'].T, dU) / loss.shape[0]
        loss = np.dot(dU, layer['w'].T)

"""# Update weights and biases (SGD optimizer)"""

def update(layers: List[ Dict[ str, np.ndarray ] ], learning_rate: float) -> None:
    for layer in layers:
        layer['w'] -= learning_rate * layer['dw']
        layer['b'] -= learning_rate * layer['db']

"""# Train model"""

def train(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, layers: List[ Dict[ str, np.ndarray ] ], epochs: int, learning_rate: float) -> None:
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
    
        # Forward propagation
        y_hat = forward(x, layers)

        # Backward propagation
        backward(y, y_hat, layers)

        # Update layers
        update(layers, learning_rate)

        # show progress
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print('Iteration nr: ', epoch, ', loss: ', binary_cross_entropy_loss(y, y_hat), ', accuracy: ', accuracy(y, y_hat))


train(x, y, dense_layers, 3001, 0.01)
```
````